# How to open LAN port to just one external WAN ip address?

Tags: networking, macos, router, firewall, port-forwarding

How do I configure my home LAN router (D-Link Dir-882) to accept communication to a LAN IP&port just from one specific WAN IP address only?

More detailed;

I have a port open on my DIR-882 Home LAN router because i routinely access it from a WAN computer using VNC software. However, my home LAN open port gets attacked by people trying to gain access.  i have tried changing ports, and changing IP addresses but the attackers keep finding my IP and open port. So, i would like to tell my home LAN DIR-882 Router to only open the specified port for traffic only to&from the WAN IP of the computer i am using. So, from the routers web GUI i selected "Turn ipv4 filtering ON and ALLOW rules listed", and entered the following rule;

Name: VNC
Source IP address range: WAN: (i typed in the WAN ip address of the computer i use to access my home computer)
Destination IP address range: LAN: (i typed in the LAN ip of my home computer)
Protocol and port range: ANY: (i typed in the port i want open on my home LAN computer)
Schedule: always enable

.... but then i couldn't browse the internet on the LAN computer.

Any guidance would be appreciated,
thank you.

ps: the LAN & WAN computers are all iMacs.

Comment: If you have the rule removed but filtering option stayed on, can the LAN computer browse internet?

Comment: the 'right' way to do this feels like a VPN, the slightly less right way would be to abuse/use ssh tunneling to secure your connection.

Comment: VPN/SSH will not eliminate the need to expose a port of a LAN host unless the router itself has that kind of server builtin though, but indeed they might be harder to be compromised when compared with VNC auth methods, and additionally the make sure the traffics are encrypted.

Comment: Do you *need* VNC, or could you do this with Screen Sharing? I can screen share to my folk's iMac  from any Mac in the world with no router config required. You can do this simply by asking to share to their AppleID. If it's someone else's ID they must be sitting there to let you in, if it's your own it's pre-authorised. It even auto-configs the mics so you can immediately speak to each other too, if you need.

Comment: @TomYan -- thank you for your comments and post. You asked what would happen if i remove the rule but leave the filter on? Without any rules, the filter will not stay on and therefor no traffic is filtered and the LAN computer can browse the internet.

Comment: @Tetsujin .. since you brought it up,  i am using vnc to screen share into my mothers computer, actually.. she is bedridden & in a nursing home and cant use a computer much less a phone.. so i control her computer remotely.. i play music and videos for her and i skype with her as well (skype is set to autoanswer but i can control it on her computer).. however, i did not create an appleid for her computer because to verify an appleid i would need a phone number to associate with it.... i could give my cell number but i dunno if that would confuse things.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek .. thank you for your comment. I thought VPN is when one computer logs into another computer then uses that computer to access the internet.. which is not what i want.. i simply want to remote desktop.. basically its screen sharing i guess?

Comment: You can use a VPN (and a PROPER USE of a VPN, despite all the glorified proxy vendors) to open a secure channel into a lan - which is what you need here. Use of VPN to share network access and such is another, though usually in a business environment

Comment: @JourneymanGeek -- you are right, i thought VPN was just a way to proxy. ...I did not realize VPN was a protocol to open a secure channel into a LAN...  hmm so i could setup a VPN to open a secured channel from the WAN into the LAN i want to remotely access & screenshare ... i will look into it.. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of googling, I found a solution posted years ago from a guy who had the same problem. http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=61517.15

In the home LAN Router d-link DIR-882 web GUI i turned on "Turn ipv4 filtering ON and ALLOW rules listed" and created the two following rules.


Rule 1

> Name: allow LAN traffic
> Source ip: LAN : 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254
> Destination ip: WAN: 1.1.1.1 - 254.254.254.254
> Protocol & Port: ANY
> Schedule: Always Enable

The above rule lets all LAN computers initiate communication to the WAN. The LAN router automatically allows in any reply from the WAN so there was no need to set any rules to allow incoming WAN communication to the LAN (see NOTE at bottom).



Rule 2

> Name: give one WAN-IP access
> Source ip: WAN: my WAN IP
> Destination ip: LAN: the LAN IP
> Protocol & Port: ANY
> Schedule: Always Enable

The above rule lets my WAN IP address, and only my WAN IP address, initiate communication to the LAN IP through -ANY- LAN port. Alternatively, there is a way to specify just one port instead of -ANY- but doing so would mean writing another rule and altering the above rule.



Lastly, using the Web GUI for the router i forwarded the LAN port i want the WAN IP to access. If you don't forward the LAN port, then the port will remain closed to the WAN even if, in the above rule, you allow the WAN to access the any port (or that specific port).



Thank you.

NOTE

> http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=48059.msg199390#msg199390
> ...if you activate "Turn IPv6 Firewall ON and ALLOW rules listed" all inbound and outbound traffic is completely blocked. In this situation you have to define at least one rule that allows outgoing traffic of any kind (which implicitly allows inbound response traffic due to the firewall's stateful inspection feature).

Special Shout out to **SuperUsers**
[M Virts](https://superuser.com/users/1709598/m-virts)
and
[Tom Yan](https://superuser.com/users/554702/tom-yan) for recognizing my problem was legitimate and pseudocoding possible solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add an ALLOW rule to permit LAN traffic out on the WAN port.

In the following I'm assuming the router will recognize 0.0.0.0/0 as the range of all IPv4 address. You can probably use 0-255.0-255.0-255.0-255 instead if it doesn't work. The DIR-882 manual doesn't specify the format.

The Lan-to-internet rule would look like

```
Source IP address range: LAN 0.0.0.0/0
Destination IP address range: WAN 0.0.0.0/0
Protocol and port range: ANY: 0-65535
```

You may also want to allow LAN clients to communicate

```
Source IP address range: LAN 0.0.0.0/0
Destination IP address range: LAN 0.0.0.0/0
Protocol and port range: ANY: 0-65535
```

If your router has a WAN ipv6 address you may want to enable similar rules for that as well.

You may also be able to switch to DENY rules instead, specifying any wan IP as the source and your LAN machine as the destination. This would prevent the firewall from blocking everything by default. The only concern with this would be splitting this rule into two ranges in order to allow your WAN host access.

Comment: Communications between the LAN clients do not normally rely on the gateway / IP forwarding part of the router but only the builtin switch (which the L3 firewall wouldn't govern) connected to its LAN interface, so LAN to LAN rule won't make much sense.

Comment: That's a good point. I could see the router still filtering LAN traffic if it's all handled by iptables internally, but Ive never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that your router handles this in a silly way, that *all* traffics (i.e., including *replying* traffics) *except* those explicitly allowed by a rule. (I'm not sure if *all* in this case would be only WAN-to-LAN traffics or even including the LAN-to-WAN ones. I suppose you'll have to test to find out.) In other words, it filters on a purely *stateless* manner.

*If that's the case*, to make it work you may need to have to have these allow rules:

> Source: 0.0.0.0/0, Destination: LAN subnet, Protocol: ANY, Port: 0-(VNC port - 1)

> Source: 0.0.0.0/0, Destination: LAN subnet, Protocol: ANY, Port: (VNC port + 1)-65535

> Source: remote WAN IP to allow, Destination: VNC computer LAN IP, Protocol: ANY, Port: VNC port

Note that traffics from WAN to other LAN computers that uses the port number of `VNC port` will also/still be blocked (and they might not necessarily be VNC traffics). So you may need even more rules.

(In fact VNC might only use the TCP port, but meh, too many rules already.)

A perhaps "smarter" approach is to allow the [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) for `0.0.0.0/0` WAN to your LAN subnet, if the VNC port number isn't within the range. Note that different OSes might use different ranges.

As someone else suggested, you might want to try the DENY / blacklisting approach instead, which might be more tricky though depending on how exactly your can enter the source IP range (like literally `A-B` or by entering a subnet address with prefix length).

---

**I would really suggest to firewall on the LAN computers themselves instead.**

Comment: http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=48059.msg199390#msg199390 ... 'if you activate "Turn IPv6 Firewall ON and ALLOW rules listed" all inbound and outbound traffic is completely blocked. In this situation you have to define at least one rule that allows outgoing traffic of any kind (which implicitly allows inbound response traffic due to the firewall's stateful inspection feature).'

Comment: In addition to the filter rules, using the router LAN GUI i must also forward the LAN port i want the WAN ip to access...say as an example 192.168.0.120:5900 ...so since LAN port 5900 is forwarded to 192.168.0.120, LAN PORT 5900 can not be used by any other computer on that LAN, or am i wrong? So then it is not a problem if the filter rule only lets one WAN IP access that LAN PORT 5900.. because 5900 will only always forwarded to 192.168.0.120 (in this example).... or am i wrong?

Comment: you said "I would really suggest to firewall on the LAN computers themselves instead." -- i looked at the firewall settings built into the macos on the LAN computer. but i dont see any obvious way to allow only one WAN IP to access the  vnc port.